# Unresolved reference when writting btnDatePicker on Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm following a course and when I write btnDatePicker I get an unresolved error:

```
package com.example.ageinminutes

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        btnDatePicker
    }
}
```

I've being searching on internet and have added a plugin on build.graddle(:app) as seen on diferent solutions:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

but it still doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by `@himel` is correct. Using kotlin synthetics is discouraged.

However I did notice that the import line for the synthetic view was not in your code. I suggest typing the view manually and importing with Android studio if you want a quick fix

Comment: Where can I find the code? Appreciate

Comment: I updated the code above with the import that I've found for the solution. Anyway it still show `btnDatePicker` as `Unresolved reference`

Comment: Sorry, maybe my initial response was a bit confusing. I didn't mean you type the import. In android studio when synthetics plugin has been setup correctly, writing the id of the view and pressing `Alt + Enter` or `Opt + Enter` on Mac will automatically add the import for you.

Comment: Also make sure your xml has a view with the matching ID... Watch this if you are confused https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrrOz6D5PEw

Comment: Have tried both solutions. sync the build.gradle with the new code. Also tried the binding option following diferent tutorials but still get btnDatePicker as unresolved reference. Even restarting Android Studio. None of the options are working.

Comment: Please check if you have a view for your activity  with id `android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"` when using syntethics or that and `android:id="@+id/btn_date_picker` when using view binding. For view binding, I would advice you follow the docs because they are very detailed https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: True! Have passed that point because on the course it doesn't tell it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

kotlin-android-extension is deprecated , you should use viewbinding instead.

Follow this : [https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration#:~:text=Kotlin%20Android%20Extensions%20is%20deprecated,migrate%20to%20Jetpack%20view%20binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration#:%7E:text=Kotlin%20Android%20Extensions%20is%20deprecated,migrate%20to%20Jetpack%20view%20binding).

Comment: Yes have tried also. But for the course I should use the old way. Being deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work. So, it should right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the button id.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32896190)